# How to make a BindingSource aware of changes in its DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I have a:

```
someBindingSource.DataSource = someDataSource;
```

And I also do:

```
someDataSource = foo();
```

`foo()` does `new` for another data source with different data.

I don't think it's correct to do the assignment every time the data source changes, i.e:

```
someDataSource = foo();
someBindingSource.DataSource = someDataSource;
```

so is there a way to make `someBindingSource` aware of change in `someDataSource`?

Comment: You are not making changes in someDataSource but replacing the entire object, So i don't think it'll be posssible without wrapping the  someDataSource  with a container and changing the data via some container method (take a look at ObservableCollection<T>)

Comment: I'll hold an ObservableCollection with one item?

Comment: I think the point is that you must wrap your dataSource object and replace the data via some method, if you want to replace the data source (instead of updating it) and still have your bindingSource be notified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data source implements [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx) inteface, then the `BindingSource` will be informed of adding or removing items to the data source. A good implementation to use is [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also if the items of the data source implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), then the `BindingSource` also will be notified of changes on items.

In above cases `ListChanged` event will be raised.

**Note**

1. Pay attention, If you assign `someBindingSource.DataSource = someThing;` and then `someThing = new SomeThing();`, since `someBindingSource.DataSource` is pointing to previous object, there is no change and there would be no notifications.
2. `DataSourceChanged` event will be raised after you assign a new value to `DataSource` of a `BindingSource`, so after `someThing = new SomeThing();` in previous situation if you perform `someBindingSource.DataSource = someThing;` then the `DataSourceChanged` will be raised.