# Updating a Label with DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, label

After my balance label is initially bound to a number, changing the datasource again doesn't update the value again.

I want to update the a Windows Form Label automatically after the database object is changed and I re-pull it into the `constructorData.BankAccount`.

```
public class ConstructorData
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
}

private void frmTransaction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pretend we populated constructor data already

    // This line of code is working
    bankAccountBindingSource.DataSource = constructorData.BankAccount;
}

private void lnkProcess_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    constructorData.BankAccount = db.BankAccounts.Where(x => x.BankAccountId == constructorData.BankAccount.BankAccountId).SingleOrDefault();

    // What do I do here

    // Doesn't work
    bankAccountBindingSource.EndEdit();
    bankAccountBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Auto generated code:

```
// 
// lblAccountBalance
// 
this.lblAccountBalance.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.lblAccountBalance.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bankAccountBindingSource, "Balance", true));
this.lblAccountBalance.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(482, 71);
this.lblAccountBalance.Name = "lblAccountBalance";
this.lblAccountBalance.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 23);
this.lblAccountBalance.TabIndex = 7;
this.lblAccountBalance.Text = "label1";
```

Comment: Not sure where the Label is in your code, but your ConstructorData class should be implementing an INotifyDataChanging interface.

Comment: @LarsTech I dragged the labels from the data source tree in visual studio so it automatically created a binding source and bound the label to it. Which code from the label would help?

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1315621/1997232).

Comment: Even if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ConstructorData` using these settings you can not make it working. You should use the Ivan's answer or the change settings as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since here (inside the form load):

```
bankAccountBindingSource.DataSource = constructorData.BankAccount;
```

you bind directly to the `BankAccount` **instance**, even implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ConstructorData` class (as suggested in the comments) will not help.

With that design, anytime you assign a new `BankAccount` instance to the `ConstructorData.BankAccount` property (as in the shown code), you need also to set it as `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` used:

```
constructorData.BankAccount = db.BankAccounts.Where(x => x.BankAccountId == constructorData.BankAccount.BankAccountId).SingleOrDefault();
// What do I do here
bankAccountBindingSource.DataSource = constructorData.BankAccount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Without Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` Ivan's answer is exactly what you need.

The reason is because you put an object in DataSource of binding source this way: `BindingSource.DataSource = constructorData.BankAccount`, so it uses the object which is in `BankAccount` property as data source. If you change the value of `constructorData.BankAccount`, you disd't changed the data source of `BindingSource` and it will contain the previous object. For example take a look at this code:

```
var a = new MyClass("1");  // ← constructorData.BankAccount = something;
var b = a;                 // ← bindingSource.DataSource = constructorData.BankAccount.
a = new MyClass("2");      // ← constructorData.BankAccount = something else;
```

What should contain `b` now? Do you expect b contains `MyClass("1")`? Surely no.

For more information take a look at this post:

- [Data Binding doesn't work when I assign a new object instance to the bound variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39821755/3110834)

**Can I use INotifyPropertyChanged to solve the problem?**

If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ConstructorData` and change bindings this way, yes:

```
bankAccountBindingSource.DataSource = constructorData;
//...
this.lblAccountBalance.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text",
    this.bankAccountBindingSource, "BankAccount.Balance", true));
```